# Can not Browse any Asp.Net File system website in any browser

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am making asp.net website in my system using web location File System. i try to browse my localhost website but it cannot be browse in any browser(Firefox,chrome etc). after searching error on google i also made changes in LAN setting of browser but still can't get any result.

*In Chrome i am receiving following error*

**"This webpage is not available
The webpage at http://localhost:2625/Website/Default.aspx might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error."**

*In Firefox i am receiving following error*

**"The connection was reset
 The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."**

How can i resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

i have resolved my problem.
i got help from following link

http://forums.asp.net/t/1437368.aspx